# How to store in a database that is retrieved from CSV files using Python

Tags: python, database, sqlite, pycharm

I want to store multiple CSV files (with different columns) and store it in database using SQLite. I also want to form relationships between these CSV files (like PK, FK) while the tables are created. After storing in the database, I want them archived so that the database storage does not keep increasing and only the newly added data gets appended to the database.

I have written the python script that will get stored in the database by reading through the CSV files. However, I want to learn how relationships can be accomplished since tables will have to be joined via different tables. I also do not know how to archive the data.

**To add more details** -

**What has to be done** - Store CSV sheets and read it via Python script and store in db. After storing it, the stored ones goes to archive one.

**What I did** - wrote a python script, read the files and stored in db. Sheets with same columns has been combined.

**What needs to be done** - relationships (connections) between the tables which has different columns. Archiving these data sets once it gets stored in db.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Really the scope of your question(s) is too wide to get any useful answers. Search on the internet, try some ways and come back with a *specific coding question* (what did not work out, where did you get stuck, etc.). As of now, your question is likely to be closed soon.

Comment: I did search all through the internet. I couldn't find the precise answer to my question since almost all the solutions either do not have relationships between the tables or no solutions to archive.

Comment: usually a slimmed down example helps.

Give show for example two csv files (the first line of each) and the structure of the sql tables, that you'd expect to show up.

and the relationship, that should have been 'auto-discovered'


For the archiving issue a slimmed down example with one csv filemight also help.